# Error in Jenkins Mac Catalina - cannot access parent directories: Operation not permitted

Tags: jenkins, macos-catalina, jenkins-cli

I updated my mac to catalina and i am starting to get this error. Before everything was working fine.

I am trying to cd into the directory from my jenkins workspace and run my npm tests and i am getting the error below:

```
shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: Operation not permitted
    + git reset --hard HEAD
    job-working-directory: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: Operation not permitted
    fatal: Unable to read current working directory: Operation not permitted
```

Comment: 3 questions: what directory is it trying to access? what user is the jenkins process running as? Is it a jenkins master or slave?

Comment: @gaige, thanks for responding. I am trying to access the folder on my desktop, it is running as master and it is my user which has admin access

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Catalina has a more complex set of permissions than previous versions of macOS X, and therefore requires you to do some additional work if you want the process to access files in certain folders, including the Desktop folder.

For normal applications, you can grant access using the System Preferences and the Privacy tab. For background applications, it's a bit more difficult, and especially with the java interpreter, but you should be able to add the java interpreter to the list of excluded Apps.

However, you may want to consider not using a folder on your Desktop to avoid this.

Comment: thank you i moved my folders from desktop and now it works

Answer (score 7):

I don't know how secure this is, but, you can also resolve this issue by going to **System preferences -> Privacy -> Full Disk Access** and giving "**/bin/sh**" full disk access.

I found this solution here: https://www.symscape.com/node/1727

Answer (score 3):

Here is the solution (MacOS Version 12.6 and later):

**System Preferences -> Privacy -> Developer Tools -> Terminal (set here the checkpoint to enabled)**

[Here comes the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GfSAg.png)

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by changing permissions:

1. Select ***.py** file.
2. Choose **Get Info** or shortcut command + I
3. Scroll to **Sharing & permissions**
4. For name **everyone** pick **Read & Write**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This works for me(Mac OS 13.3 or later) :
**System Preferences** -> **Privacy & Security** -> **Full Disk Access** -> **Terminal** (set here the checkpoint to enabled)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).